# HTTP GET request in Javascript with Cookie?

Tags: javascript, http, cookies, get, request

I need to do an HTTP GET request in JS, with a pre-definied cookie.

What would be the best way to to that?

Found that, with many ways to do an request, but found no one that supports cookies...
[HTTP GET request in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript)

Comment: do the cookies will be parameter to the url? like abc.com?x=5 here the value 5 will come from cookie

Comment: @kundan Karn:
A Cookie like saved in the Browser (login cookie)

Comment: If you make an AJAX request, you can add custom HTTP headers to it … so one of those could be a Cookie header.

Comment: @CBroe:
Would you have an example for me?

Answer (score 1):

```
    if(!isset($_COOKIE["cookiename"])) {
        setcookie("cookiename","cookievalue");
    } else {
        // This is propably the 2nd call of that site (with cookie)
        // Here your code comes
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set cookies for a specific request, but you can edit cookies on the clientside if you set them as such.

This [cookies script](https://code.google.com/p/cookies/) abstracts this aways a bit, because you only have access to the full string, containing all of the cookies in one via `document.cookie`, natively.

Depending on you want to do, you might be better off setting `GET` parameters instead.

Comment: If a make an JS request, the cookies from the Browser will be used?
This would solve my whole problem...
I can only change the cookies from the website the JS is hosted on right?

Comment: AJAX requests include all cookies your browser would normally send for that request, yes.

Comment: Would this work with an request like this?

new Ajax.Request( '/myurl', {
  method:  'get',
  parameters:  { 'param1': 'value1'},
  onSuccess:  function(response){
    alert(response.responseText);
  },
  onFailure:  function(){
    alert('ERROR');
  }
});

Comment: This would send all cookies like normal and they would be accessible on the server. :)